# how to find out the full name of Java class in DropWizard logs

Tags: java, dropwizard

We are using DropWizard in a Java based micro-service. In the logs, we have lines like:

```
[dw-1000 - POST myservice/endpoint] c.s.x.m.s.c.p2p - my error message
```

My question is: how can I find out the full names of the Java class path represented as "c.s.x.m.s.c.p2p" in the above log message?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there is a format tring that can be configured: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/manual/configuration.html#logging

Comment: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the default configuration in your yaml:
The **logFormat** is the key to your solution - %c displays the full logger name, and if there is no number followed, it's the full name with no name-cuts:

```
logging:
  appenders:
    - type: file
      ...
      logFormat: '[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%-5level] [%c] [%thread] [-[%msg]-] %n'
```